# Multiple child instances of same object , change value instead of just selected instance

Tags: python, instance, kivy

I am just what I am doing wrong, Thanks for any heads up and your patience :)

below I am creating 100 instances of the sticker object(from the class sticker) in the Demo Class and adding them as children to the root widget, but only using 1 variable name, is this the correct way of doing things, because at the present moment when the touch down method of the sticker class is triggered all instances change value , instead of just the instance I happen to touch.

```
    # root widget creation
class rootwidget(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(rootwidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

# sticker object, WIP , labeltype,pos,size place holders
class sticker(Label):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self.labeltype = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
        self.xf = 0
        self.yf = 0
        super(sticker,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.text = str(self.labeltype[random.randint(0,len(self.labeltype)-1)])
        self.pos_hint = self.generateposhint()
        self.size_hint = size_hint=(0.01,0.01)

    # place holder for testing touch down, method to be more relevant once basics are nailed.
    def on_touch_down(self,instance):
        self.text = "T"

        #main app     
class demo(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = root = rootwidget()


        return self.root


       #place holder loop. while testing ,to be moved into method
        while i < 200:
            lb = sticker()
            self.root.add_widget(lb)
            i = i + 1


if __name__=='__main__':
    demo().run()
```

Comment: It would really help if you explained your question with reference to the code, and even better if you also marked up the code to indicate the problematic part.

Comment: Apologies Marcin, I will take note for next time, thanks )

Comment: Damn, I've tried to come up with a good Lord of the Rings joke here, something like "200 instances were created under `while`, but one root to rule them all" ... but I can't think of something catchy :-/ But seriously, try to make a good title. More than one `?` might be an indicator that you should edit it (except if it's a LaTeX-references-question)

Comment: lol will do moose thanks :)

Comment: @DeadZero Don't take note of it for next time, amend your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your question is about the following snippet:

```
    while i < 200:
        lb = sticker()
        self.root.add_widget(lb)
        i = i + 1
```

basically here you create 200 instances of `sticker`. 
For each of them, you use the variable to store a reference to the sticker instance, and then you add that instance to `root`.

So basically, you end up having 200 instances of sticker that are referenced from the `root` instance as widget children. But you don't have all the references easy to access, though you may still be able to access them through your `root` widget.

> should I be creating a different variable names for each instance?

Well, I don't think you want to have 200 variable names in your code ;-)

> (if so how do it dynamically) and assigning them to a list? then adding them?

but more seriously, yes, you *can* add them to a list. It all depends on what those widgets are used for, and whether or not you need a convenient access to those references.

e.g.:

```
sticker_list = []
for i in range(0,200):
    s = sticker()
    sticker_list.append(s)
    self.root.add_widget(s)
```

But as I said this may be useful or useless depending on what you want your code to do. Usually, if you want to handle user interaction, it's better to handle them using callback events, read more kivy examples to know more about that.

Comment: Thanks zmo, yea they are all added to the root, so they are viewable, how would I adjust them so they were easy references and accessible? and when I touch just 1 / 200 only that one changes?, I'm still studying classes and oop from some posts link given on here...it doesn't come easy :/lol

Comment: Yes, only that one change. I guess you need to understand the difference between a variable, a reference and an instance. You have 200 instances in your memory, and the variable is a reference of one instance at a given moment. If you *really* need it, you can keep all the references in a list by declaring `sticker_list=[]` before the loop, and replacing `lb = sticker()` with `sticker_list.append(sticker())`

Comment: Thanks zmo, I will add those to my read list , before attempting to fix it, new to the scene and lingo, so thanks for bearing with me.